# IMAP settings not working using Godaddy settings

Tags: imap

Below is the code I am using for imap to fetch emails.

```
$hostname = '{imap.secureserver.net:993/imap/ssl/}INBOX';
$username = 'xyz@domain.com';
$password = 'emailpassword';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password,NULL,1) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . print_r(imap_errors()));
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Array ( [0] => Can't open mailbox {imap.secureserver.net:993/imap/ssl/}INBOX: invalid remote specification ) Cannot connect to Gmail: 1
```

Comment: You have an extra / at the end of your specification.  It should be `/imap/ssl`

Comment: still Not working

Comment: Does anyone have working example ?

Comment: Did you solve this?